# Open Layers kml layer labels

Tags: openlayers, kml, openlayers-3

I define the following KML Layer with open layers:

```
  var vector2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: "./myPolygons.kml",
            format: new ol.format.KML({extractStyles: false})
        }),
        style: styleFunction
    });
```

The Problem is i want to label my Polygonfeatures with a text.
The text comes from the feature Name.
This is working when i call the styleFunction, but only when i set the: extractStyles: false
When i set it to false i lose all the styles which are defined in the kml file.

Is there any way to label polygons from a kml file and keep the original styles from the kml File?
In openlayers 2 this was working..

Thank your very much.
Steve